# Django: "Login with Facebook" button not working after deployed to pythonanywhere

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth, pythonanywhere

When I run the app in localhost, it works fine. but after deployed to pythonanywhere, **Login with Facebook** button doesn't work.

when I refresh **Login page**, in console, it shows =>

```
Failed to load resource: https://username.pythonanywhere.com/static/facebook/js/fbconnect.js the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Refused to execute https://username.pythonanywhere.com/static/facebook/js/fbconnect.js as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
```

in template:

```
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'facebook' method='js_sdk' %}"><button class="effect" style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(58, 110, 255); height: 36px; border: none; color: white; border-radius: 3px; display: flex; justify-content: center;align-items: center;"><img style="height: 24px; width: 24px; background-color: white; padding: 1px; border-radius: 50%;" src="{% static 'images/fblogo.png' %}" alt=""><span style="margin-top: 2px; display: block; margin-left: 8px; font-size: 16px;"> Login with Facebook</span></button></a> <br>
```

> Another problem is: CSS doesn't load in admin page

how to fix this?

> Edit: now if i click "Login with facebook" button, it shows, `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: allauth`

what to do now?

Comment: For css part [check this](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles/)

Comment: Also check https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/StaticFiles in general

Comment: in my static folder, there are one css file (that i created) and three folder (1.admin, 2. facebook, 3. images(also i created that). how to setup now?

Comment: @AsifBiswas Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` and `reload` from web tab in pythonanywhere ?

Comment: @Prakhar , Yes, I did that